# Entity Framework/LINQ/MSSQL vs Entity Framework/LINQ/MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

My question is this. When trying to decide between using the Entity Framework and LINQ to SQL as an ORM, I am trying to figure out whether to use MSSQL or MYSQL....which one is preferred?

I heard that LINQ to SQL is tied to SQL Server is that still true?

NET integration story (C#, Linq, Entity Framework, etc.) in SQL Server is better is what I heard,please share your opinions

Answer (score 0):

LINQ to SQL was introduced as part of .net 3.5 from memory. I don't see why you'd use it over EntityFramework now however, EF has come a long way and provides as far as I'm aware all the features LINQ to SQL did:
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6

Comment: So Kris,my another question when using EF ,is it preferable to use MSSQL or MYSQL?

Comment: Either work well, I use MS SQL at work and MySQL for my personal stuff. The benefit of using MySQL is that its open source and free. Some of the biggest apps in the world use it (SO use MS SQL), so there aren't any issues scaling wise. Also does master-master replication which is cool. IIRC Azure have a single database sql instance for around 5 US a month. Just another cost on top of hosting.

EntityFramework has a raft of adapters that allow other database engines to be used in place of MS SQL. You can get the MySQL adapter from here:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.Entity/

Answer (score 0):

EF and Linq to Sql are both Microsoft products, and SQL Server is a Microsoft product.  Mysql is not a Microsoft product.  In my experience, things work better if you stick with the same vendor.  If you go with EF or Linq to SQL, and you have no other reasons to choose one over the other, my guess is you'll be happier if you pair it with SQL Server.